# Med base vs deep base paint

Tags: painting

I want a dark color exterior paint but have a medium base paint. If I use a dark paint formula in the medium base what will happen?

Comment: You'll need to check with the manufacturer of the medium based paint you have.

Answer (score 3):

### It will come out paler and lighter than you expect.

If it were a [Munsell sheet](https://munsell.com/about-munsell-color/how-color-notation-works/how-to-read-color-chart/), it will move your color up (lighter) and to the left (less saturation).

The "base" is a huge part of the overall pigmenting.

You may notice that *the vast majority* of architectural coatings (house paint) are off-whites.  They're not even pastel; pastel like Miami style would get a nasty letter from the HOA. **They are off-white**.

So imagine paint had no pigment in it. You pick your HOA-acceptable house paint color, present the chip to the mixer, and the formula says "0.8 pumps of yellow, 1.6 pumps of blue, **and 55 pumps of white**.  *Well, how is that supposed to work?  It's completely impractical*.

The industry answer for that is the various bases - light, medium and deep.  The white base comes pre-loaded with 50 pumps of white (let's say), so the formula will call for "white base + 5 white + 0.8 yellow + 1.6 blue" and that's reasonable.

The light base has less, the medium base has less, and the deep base has **essentially none**.  Because when you need to go for the very high-saturation colors, you can't have any white in the mix pasteling it out.

So if your paint formula calls for a deep base, you're outta luck.  The XRite computer that figured out that formula picked the deep base because the medium base has too much white in it to be usable for that formula.

Sorry, that's how it is.

### How the heck did that even happen!!!???

I just don't understand how it's physically possible for a customer to grab a can of base that hasn't been tinted. Most shops don't put it out, because customer-side shelf space is precious.  Any paint store manager is going to flag you at checkout and not let you walk out with it untinted, because that will inevitably result in an angry customer trying to return it.

This smells like big box store stupidity, because they don't have a back room to keep it in, and nobody at the register knows to not let you walk out with untinted base.

Well, here's the thing. **The tinting *is part of* the price**.* So you paid for the tints, and didn't get them.

So back to the store you should go, and be the angry customer they richly deserve.  You might approach it by saying "here's the can I previously bought, and here's my paint chip (which has the formula on it), **is this the right base for that formula?**" If they're any good, they'll say "NO" and offer to swap you for the right base if it's unopened.

And pro tip, stop buying at big-box stores. They suck.  The trade doesn't buy there, for reasons.

---

* Except for the 2-part trade paints I buy, which use *extremely* high quality pigments, and the price difference on certain pigments can double the price.

Comment: Just to add, if you do need to discard the medium base and buy new, think about the proportionate cost of materials vs labor. (Hint: paint makes up very little of the cost. Even if it’s your own labor, that isn’t free.)